# How to read D3 node label text into a div/paragraph element?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm working with a force labelled graph layout in D3 and one of my project requirements is that the text associated with each node should show up in a div/p element that occupies a fixed position on the web page instead of showing up directly adjacent to the concerned node (currently it activates on mouse hover). So every time a user hovers on any node, the corresponding text should show up in the div tag and not right next to the node in the graph.

The following code snippets show how I'm currently working with my nodes and labels:

```
var node = vis.selectAll(".node")
        .data(nodes)
        .enter().append("g")
        .attr("class", "node")
        .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; })
        .call(force.drag);

    node.append("text")
        .text("");

force.on("tick", function() {
        nodes[0].x = w / 2;
        nodes[0].y = h / 2;

        link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
            .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
            .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
            .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

        node.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });

node.on("mouseover", function(d){       
        node.classed("node-active", function(o) {
            thisOpacity = isConnected(d, o) ? true : false;
            this.setAttribute('fill-opacity', thisOpacity);
            return thisOpacity;
        });

        link.classed("link-active", function(o) {
            return o.source === d || o.target === d ? true : false;
        });

        d3.select(this).classed("node-active", true);
        d3.select(this).select("circle").transition()
            .duration(500)
            .attr("r", 20);
        d3.select(this).select("text")
            .attr("dx", 12)
            .attr("dy", ".35em")
            .text(function(d) { return d.label; });
        d3.select(this).select("circle")
            .on("click", function(d){
                var win = window.open(d.label, '_blank');
                win.focus();
            });
    })

    .on("mouseout", function(d){
        node.classed("node-active", false);
        link.classed("link-active", false);     

        d3.select(this).select("circle").transition()
            .duration(750)
            .attr("r", 10);
        d3.select(this).select("text")
            .text("");
    });
```

I have a div tag with id = 'nodeLabel' that will be used to print the node's label. I hope the attached code helps. I tried using document.getElementById('nodeLabel') to set it's value but I'm not sure if this is the right approach or where would this line of code go?

How do I achieve the desired effect?

Answer (score 1):

In your mouseover handler, simply add something like this:

```
$("#nodeLabel").text(d.label);
```

Building on your code, this would result in:

```
node.on("mouseover", function(d){       
    node.classed("node-active", function(o) {
        thisOpacity = isConnected(d, o) ? true : false;
        this.setAttribute('fill-opacity', thisOpacity);
        return thisOpacity;
    });

    link.classed("link-active", function(o) {
        return o.source === d || o.target === d ? true : false;
    });

    d3.select(this).classed("node-active", true);
    d3.select(this).select("circle").transition()
        .duration(500)
        .attr("r", 20);
    d3.select(this).select("circle")
        .on("click", function(d){
            var win = window.open(d.label, '_blank');
            win.focus();
        });

    $("#nodeLabel").text(d.label);
})
```

Comment: I'm not sure how to use this in my code. Can you elaborate or show me a sample?

Comment: I added the relevant part of your code example in my answer. I added the last line in the function, and removed the original code to set the text in the label.

Answer (score 0):

I would go about it probably by

1. At the beginning, when you create the nodes, you call `.each()` and pass it a function that sets a member variable of each of the nodes to the value you want to display.
2. In the `onClick` handler, you can get the element, on which the event occured, by `d3.select(this)` so I would take from it the value you stored in step 1 and set the div's text accordingly. Which would be something like `d3.select("#nodeLabel").text(nodeText)`

Comment: So do you mean I could create an array for node values and then based on which 'index' select(this) returns, load the corresponding value in the div tag?

Comment: Is there a way to directly pass the specific node's text into the div tag?

Comment: No not an array, you can store the value directly in the element. 
And as for the second - If you use the `.text()` method without a parameter, it returns the text content of the element.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found a way to do it.

I stored the value of d.label into a variable and then simply set the innerHTML of the 'p' tag in the mouseOver handle.

Here's the updated code snippet:

```
node.on("mouseover", function(d){       
        node.classed("node-active", function(o) {
            thisOpacity = isConnected(d, o) ? true : false;
            this.setAttribute('fill-opacity', thisOpacity);
            return thisOpacity;
        });

        link.classed("link-active", function(o) {
            return o.source === d || o.target === d ? true : false;
        });

        var nodeText; 
        d3.select(this).classed("node-active", true);
        d3.select(this).select("circle").transition()
            .duration(500)
            .attr("r", 20);
        d3.select(this).select("text")
            .attr("dx", 12)
            .attr("dy", ".35em")
            .text(function(d) { nodeText = d.label; return d.label; });
        d3.select("#nodeLabel").text(nodeText)
        d3.select(this).select("circle")
            .on("click", function(d){
                var win = window.open(d.label, '_blank');
                win.focus();
            });
        console.log(nodeText);
        document.getElementById('nodeLabel').innerHTML = "Node selected: "+nodeText;
    })
```

If there's a simpler/better solution, I would definitely still like to hear it and learn!

Comment: There's no need to store this in a separate variable, as you can see in my answer. In the question, you mentioned that you wanted the text in the specified div instead of next to the node. Your solution still shows the text next to the node. My answer perfectly addresses your question.